# Comparison for objects derived from std::string_view is ambiguous in MSVC

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++17, std

**TL;DR:**
Can I expect that the code below will compile on any c++17 conformant c++ toolchain (based on the current c++17 proposal) and the failure of MSVC to do so is a bug in their implementation?

```
#include <string_view>

struct Foo : std::string_view {};

int main() {
  Foo f1{};
  Foo f2{};
  return f1 == f2;
}
```

**Explanation:**
I have a class that is derived from `std::string_view` and doesn't implement its own comparison operators, because the `std::string_view` semantics are exactly what I need and I also want it to be comparable to e.g. a `std::string`.

However, if I try to compare two instances of that class, MSVC 2017 complains about multiple overloads with similar conversions:

```
example.cpp
/opt/compiler-explorer/windows/19.10.25017/lib/native/include/xlocale(314): warning C4530: C++ exception handler used, but unwind semantics are not enabled. Specify /EHsc
8 : <source>(8): error C2666: 'std::operator ==': 3 overloads have similar conversions
/opt/compiler-explorer/windows/19.10.25017/lib/native/include/exception(336): note: could be 'bool std::operator ==(const std::exception_ptr &,const std::exception_ptr &) throw()' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
/opt/compiler-explorer/windows/19.10.25017/lib/native/include/exception(341): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(std::nullptr_t,const std::exception_ptr &) throw()' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
/opt/compiler-explorer/windows/19.10.25017/lib/native/include/exception(346): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::exception_ptr &,std::nullptr_t) throw()' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
/opt/compiler-explorer/windows/19.10.25017/lib/native/include/system_error(362): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_code &,const std::error_code &) noexcept' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
/opt/compiler-explorer/windows/19.10.25017/lib/native/include/system_error(370): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_code &,const std::error_condition &) noexcept' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
/opt/compiler-explorer/windows/19.10.25017/lib/native/include/system_error(378): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_code &) noexcept' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
/opt/compiler-explorer/windows/19.10.25017/lib/native/include/system_error(386): note: or       'bool std::operator ==(const std::error_condition &,const std::error_condition &) noexcept' [found using argument-dependent lookup]
/opt/compiler-explorer/windows/19.10.25017/lib/native/include/xstring(970): note: or       'bool std::operator ==<char,std::char_traits<char>>(const std::basic_string_view<char,std::char_traits<char>>,const std::basic_string_view<char,std::char_traits<char>>) noexcept'
/opt/compiler-explorer/windows/19.10.25017/lib/native/include/xstring(980): note: or       'bool std::operator ==<char,std::char_traits<char>,Foo&,void>(_Conv,const std::basic_string_view<char,std::char_traits<char>>) noexcept(<expr>)'
        with
        [
            _Conv=Foo &
        ]
/opt/compiler-explorer/windows/19.10.25017/lib/native/include/xstring(990): note: or       'bool std::operator ==<char,std::char_traits<char>,Foo&,void>(const std::basic_string_view<char,std::char_traits<char>>,_Conv) noexcept(<expr>)'
        with
        [
            _Conv=Foo &
        ]
8 : <source>(8): note: while trying to match the argument list '(Foo, Foo)'
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.10.25017 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
Compiler exited with result code 2
```

I do not know, why the the first few overloads (e.g. with `std::error_code`) are listed at all. As the error message itself only talks about 3 overloads I guess they are only there for completeness, but are not part of the problem.

What confuses me however are those two overloads:

```
bool std::operator ==<char,std::char_traits<char>,Foo&,void>(_Conv,const std::basic_string_view<char,std::char_traits<char>>) noexcept(<expr>)
bool std::operator ==<char,std::char_traits<char>,Foo&,void>(const std::basic_string_view<char,std::char_traits<char>>,_Conv) noexcept(<expr>)
```

I could not find any mention of them on `cppreference.com` and the code compiles fine under clang and gcc: https://godbolt.org/g/4Lj5qv, so they are probably not present in their implementation.

**So my question is**

- Is their existence actually allowed (or even mandated) by the expected c++17 standard or is that a bug in MSVC?
- If something like this is allowed in a standard conforming c++ standard library, is there a simple workaround that doesn't require me to implement all the comparators myself (I know, they are trivial to write, but it should imho not be necessary and I'd have to repeat the process for multiple types).

**EDIT**:
Just for reference, the actual `Foo` is an immutable string class very similar to this one: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116010/yet-another-immutable-string, but in order to simplify the design I wanted to replace my hand-rolled `str_ref` with `std::string_view`

Comment: "The implementation shall provide sufficient additional constexpr and noexcept overloads of these functions so that a basic_string_view<CharT,Traits> object sv may be compared to another object t with an implicit conversion to basic_string_view<CharT,Traits>, with semantics identical to comparing sv and basic_string_view<CharT,Traits>(t). " --http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string_view/operator_cmp

Comment: @cpplearner: Stupid me - I should have read the complete page and not just the declarations. That still leaves the question, if above code is supposed to compile (the way I understand the text, the intention is that it should)

Comment: Generally, it is not considered a good practice to derive from standard library classes like that. It can cause object slicing among other for example if a function that a `std::string_view` parameter by value. If you want your own class, then I would suggest to use composition instead (and no implicit conversion from/to the internal object). That way, you won't have any surprise as any potential problem could be detected at compilation time.

Comment: @Phil1970: Can you give a specific example of where deriving from `std::string_view` might cause problems? Or is that just unreflected repetition of "common wisdom"? Yes, in theory the non-virtual destructor could be a problem but can you imagine any reasonable code where you write `delete some_ptr_to_string_view` or have a `std::unique_ptr<string_view>`? Also, I know what object slicing is, but again, I can't imagine a case where that would be a problem.

Comment: Btw.: My class `Foo` is essentially a custom string implementation that SHOULD be implicitly convertible to `std::string_view` anyway. Also the interface should provide a superset of what `std::string_view` provides, so why should I reimplement all those functions myself (even if they just forward the call)?

Comment: **It is common wisdom...** If you want to provide more operations on such type, it is preferable to either use free functions or an helper class. If you want to use your own type in your code, then it is preferable to use composition instead and only provide methods you need so that your class won't be misused.

Comment: @Phil1970: Once again, please name a specific concern about what could happen, when I inherit from `std::string_view`. Not general guidelines, that might be right in the majority of cases, but as all guidelines do have exceptions. Just to make clear, what I'm talking about, the actual class behind `Foo`is very similar to this `const_string`(https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/116010/yet-another-immutable-string). I **WANT a strict superset** of `std::string_view`'s interface and I need additional state.

Comment: In particular, I claim that it is far more likely that I make some mistake while reimplementing the interface of `std::string_view` then when using the class. The only case I can imagine how to misuse the class is if I had a function, that takes an `std::string_view` as a parameter by non-const reference and reassigns it internally (that is the actual case, where object slicing is a problem, NOT when taking std::string_view by value).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you should expect your code to work; template argument deduction can deduce the base class in function calls, see [[temp.deduct.call]/4.3](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#4.3)

> — If `P` is a class and `P` has the form *simple-template-id*, then the transformed `A` can be a derived class of the deduced `A`.

**The issue with VS 2017 (15.3)** is - the standard also has provisions for situations when one of the arguments is *implicitly-convertible* to `std::string_view`, see [[string.view.comparison]](http://eel.is/c++draft/string.view#comparison):

> Let `S` be `basic_­string_­view<charT, traits>`, and `sv` be an
>   instance of `S`. Implementations shall provide sufficient additional
>   overloads marked `constexpr` and `noexcept` so that an object `t` with
>   an implicit conversion to `S` can be compared according to Table 67.
>
> Table 67 — Additional `basic_­string_­view` comparison overloads
>
> - Expression `t == sv`  equivalent to: `S(t) == sv`
> - Expression `sv == t`  equivalent to: `sv == S(t)`
> - . . .
>
> [ Example: A sample conforming implementation for `operator==` would be:
>
> ```
> template<class T> using __identity = decay_t<T>;
> template<class charT, class traits>
>   constexpr bool operator==(basic_string_view<charT, traits> lhs,
>                             basic_string_view<charT, traits> rhs) noexcept {
>     return lhs.compare(rhs) == 0;
>   }
> template<class charT, class traits>
>   constexpr bool operator==(basic_string_view<charT, traits> lhs,
>                             __identity<basic_string_view<charT, traits>> rhs) noexcept {
>     return lhs.compare(rhs) == 0;
>   }
> template<class charT, class traits>
>   constexpr bool operator==(__identity<basic_string_view<charT, traits>> lhs,
>                             basic_string_view<charT, traits> rhs) noexcept {
>     return lhs.compare(rhs) == 0;
>   }
> ```
>
> — end example ]

This causes a problem in VS 2017 (15.3) because:

- The MSVC compiler can't handle [partial ordering of function templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45769950/partial-ordering-of-function-templates-and-non-deduced-context-not-working-in-ms) w.r.t. non-deduced context (thanks @T.C.), so the implementation mentioned in the standard is **not possible**
- Consequently, the MSVC standard library works around that with SFINAE for overloads #2 and #3, see `xstring`:

> ```
> template<class _Elem,
>   class _Traits,
>   class _Conv, // TRANSITION, VSO#265216
>   class = enable_if_t<is_convertible<_Conv, basic_string_view<_Elem, _Traits>>::value>>
>   _CONSTEXPR14 bool operator==(_Conv&& _Lhs, const basic_string_view<_Elem, _Traits> _Rhs)
>       _NOEXCEPT_OP(_NOEXCEPT_OP((basic_string_view<_Elem, _Traits>(_STD forward<_Conv>(_Lhs)))))
>   {   // compare objects convertible to basic_string_view instances for equality
>   return (_Rhs._Equal(_STD forward<_Conv>(_Lhs)));
>   }
>
> template<class _Elem,
>   class _Traits,
>   class _Conv, // TRANSITION, VSO#265216
>   class = enable_if_t<is_convertible<_Conv, basic_string_view<_Elem, _Traits>>::value>>
>   _CONSTEXPR14 bool operator==(const basic_string_view<_Elem, _Traits> _Lhs, _Conv&& _Rhs)
>       _NOEXCEPT_OP(_NOEXCEPT_OP((basic_string_view<_Elem, _Traits>(_STD forward<_Conv>(_Rhs)))))
>   {   // compare objects convertible to basic_string_view instances for equality
>   return (_Lhs._Equal(_STD forward<_Conv>(_Rhs)));
>   }
> ```

Unfortunately this is *not the same as what was meant in the standard* -  since the signature of these overloads differs from the original one, and `Foo&&` is a better match than `std::string_view` (again thanks @T.C.), no partial ordering between #1, #2 and #3 is performed - overload resolution selects #2 and #3 as better candidates. Now these two are truly ambiguous - both are viable yet neither is more specialized.

As a workaround you can implement comparators for your types, or just a generic comparator for when both sides are convertible to `string_view`:

```
#include <string_view>

template<class T, class T2,
  class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<T, std::string_view>::value>,
  class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<T2, std::string_view>::value>>
constexpr bool operator==(T&& lhs, T2&& rhs) noexcept
{
  return lhs.compare(std::forward<T2>(rhs));
}

struct Foo : std::string_view {};

int main() {
  Foo f1{};
  Foo f2{};
  return f1 == f2;
}
```

Comment: That is unfortunate news, but thanks anyway.
I'd been completely happy with the slicing btw. - don't see how that could have been a problem.

Comment: Partial ordering should pick the neither-non-deduced overload in the standard's sample implementation (or at least that's what Clang and GCC are doing). The issue with MSVC's implementation is that it uses a different set of signatures.

Comment: In MSVC's case, the extra overloads take `_Conv&&` which is a better match compared to the 2-`string_view` overload. Partial ordering doesn't come into play here.

Comment: @T.C. - Unfortunately the MS compiler also fails doing partial ordering if using the sample code from the standard. The `_Conv&&` is probably intended as a workaround for that, but far from perfect obviously.