# Partial ordering of function templates and non-deduced context not working in MSVC 2017

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

The `identity` template is a common idiom for switching off deduction for a certain (dependent) template argument, for example to allow for implicit conversions like in the example below:

```
#include <iostream>

template<class T>
struct A {};
struct B : public A<int> {};
struct C {
  operator B() { return {}; }
};

template<typename U> struct identity { typedef U type; };

template<class T> using identity_t = typename identity<T>::type;

template<class X>
void test(A<X> arg1, A<X> arg2) {              // #1
  std::cout << "ok1";
}

template<class X>
void test(A<X> arg1, identity_t<A<X>> arg2) {  // #2
  std::cout << "ok2";
}

int main() {
  B a, b;
  C c;
  test(a, b);
  test(b, c);
}
```

But the results from different compilers are not the same: [Live demo on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/nXHW2D)

- GCC 6: `ok1ok2`
- clang 5: `ok1ok2`
- MSVC 2017:

> ```
> 27 : <source>(27): error C2668: 'test': ambiguous call to overloaded function
> 20 : <source>(20): note: could be 'void test<int>(A<int>,A<int>)'
> 15 : <source>(15): note: or       'void test<int>(A<int>,A<int>)'
> 27 : <source>(27): note: while trying to match the argument list '(B, B)'
> ```

The error kind of makes sense (although is surely a bug in MSVC) and thus brings us to my questions about **why and how it works in GCC and clang**:

1. How does `test(a, b)` select `#1` while `test(b, c)` - `#2`? They look like equally good candidates at least in case `test(a, b)`.
2. Why isn't the compiler complaining about two `test` instantiations with an exact same signature?

Comment: About 2. - I would guess it's because of a "first matching template wins" logic. But that does not explain 1. at all...

Comment: (1.) They are not equally good.  Otherwise the compiler would signal an ambiguity.  `test(a, b)` will select #1 because `a` and `b` are both `A<X>` in an is-a relationship and #1 is an exact match.  #2 would also be an exact match but needs more steps.

Comment: On [a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45751978/comparison-for-objects-derived-from-stdstring-view-is-ambiguous-in-msvc) yesterday, the agreement seems to be that MSVC doesn't fully implement partial ordering.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in MSVC, the program is correct.

> ***How does `test(a, b)` select `#1`?***

For `test(a, b)`, overload resolution performs argument deduction from a function call (see [[temp.deduct.call]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.deduct.call)):

- #1 is deduced as `void test(A<int>, A<int>)`
- #2 is deduced as `void test(A<int>, <non-deduced context>)`, arg2 is then synthesized from arg1 as `A<int>`, the result: `void test(A<int>, A<int>)`

There is more than one viable alternative, so the process continues with *partial ordering* (see [[temp.deduct.partial]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.deduct.partial)).

Partial ordering uses the *original* templates, trying a *deduction from a type* ([[temp.deduct.type]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.deduct.type)) pair-wise of each argument of one template into another (after a minor conversion), and vice versa.
If the deduction succeeds in only one direction, the winning template is selected as the most specialized.

Deduction from a type *always fails* at nested contexts (anything to the left of the scope operator `::` is a nested context), see [[temp.deduct.type]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.deduct.type#5):

> The non-deduced contexts are:
>
> — The *[nested-name-specifier](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.prim.general#nt:nested-name-specifier)* of a type that was specified using a *[qualified-id](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/expr.prim.general#nt:qualified-id)*.
>
> . . .

So this means that #2 will always lose in partial ordering; the deduction into it will always fail, whereas the other way will always succeed:

1. Deducing `void test(A<T>,A<T>)` from `void test(A<U>, typename identity<A<U>>::type)` : P1=`A<T>`, A1=`A<U>`, P2=`A<U>`, A2=`A<U>`, success, T=`U`
2. Deducing `void test(A<T>, typename identity<A<T>>::type)` from `void test(A<U>,A<U>)` : P1=`A<T>`, A1=`A<U>`, P2=`<non-deduced-context>`, fail

So the outcome of partial ordering is: use `void test(A<T>,A<T>)` (#1) for the call `test(a, b)`.

> ***How does `test(b, c)` select `#2`?***

For `test(b, c)`, `A<X>` cannot be deduced from `C` (implicit conversions are not considered during deduction), so #2 is the only viable alternative. `identity_t<A<X>>` is resolved *after* deduction to `A<int>`, since `X` is known (deduced from the first argument).

> ***Why isn't the compiler complaining about two test instantiations with an exact same signature?***

The template parameters referenced in the function declaration are part of the signature of the instantiated function. See [[temp.over.link]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/temp.over.link#1):

> 1. It is possible to overload function templates so that two different function template specializations have the same type.
> 2. Such specializations are distinct functions and do not violate the one-definition rule.